# Why live prestashop throws error in localhost?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I have followed all the steps mentioned in 
[How to move live prestashop site to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755521/how-to-move-live-prestashop-site-to-localhost)
Still getting this error
[image: prestashop error]

Comment: There is output to the browser before you call `session_start()`

Comment: side note, why is this tagged mysql - ubuntu - phpmyadmin ? Only use relevant tags, in this case PHP and Prestashop-1.7

Answer (score 1):

In config>defines.inc.php,
Instead of 
`define('_PS_MODE_DEV',true)`

Set this value to false
`define('_PS_MODE_DEV',false)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).